# Sorting in xslt and choosing minimum or maximum value

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Need some help in sorting and then choosing either maximum or minimum value in XSLT.

Source xml:

```
<target>
<relatedTarget>
<permitExpiry>2005-07-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
<permitStart>2015-07-11T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
</relatedTarget>

<relatedTarget>
<permitExpiry>2003-07-12T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
<permitStart>2014-07-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
</relatedTarget>

<relatedTarget>
<permitExpiry>2002-07-10T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
<permitStart>2016-07-06T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
</relatedTarget>
</target>
```

Result xml:

```
<target>
<relatedTarget>
<permitStart>2014-07-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
<permitExpiry>2005-07-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
</relatedTarget>
</target>
```

Basically i need the result should have minimum permitStart date and maximum permitExpiry date from among all the dates comming.

My sample xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">


<xsl:variable name="permitStartVar" select="//permitStart"/>        
<xsl:variable name="permitStopVar" select="//permitExpiry"/>        

<xsl:for-each select="relatedTask">     
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,1,4)" /> <!-- Year -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,6,2)" /> <!-- Month -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,9,2)" /> <!-- Day -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,12,2)" /> <!-- Hour -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,15,2)" /> <!-- Minute -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,18,2)" /> <!-- Second -->


<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,1,4)" /> <!-- Year -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,6,2)" /> <!-- Month -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,9,2)" /> <!-- Day -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,12,2)" /> <!-- Hour -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,15,2)" /> <!-- Minute -->
<xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,18,2)" /> <!-- Second --> 
</xsl:for-each>

<target>
<relatedTarget>
<permitStart><xsl:value-of select="$permitStartVar[1]"/></permitStart>
<permitExpiry><xsl:value-of select="$permitStopVar[last()]"/></permitExpiry>
</relatedTarget>    
</target>

</template>
```

Comment: Please post your actual sample xsl and xml, since neither are actually valid xml or xsl, as well as your desired Output! For the sorting you do not have to split it up like that, if you just sort by permitStart, you should have the same result, because the date string is already in the same order as when you split it up.

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9? Then simply sort on `xs:dateTime(permitExpiry)` as XSLT 2.0 has support for that xs:dateTime data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I follow your approach ,

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="target">
  <xsl:variable name="permitStartVar" select="//permitStart"/>
  <xsl:variable name="permitStopVar" select="//permitExpiry"/>
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
     <xsl:for-each select="relatedTarget/permitStart">
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,1,4)"/>
        <!--Year-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,6,2)"/>
        <!--Month-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,9,2)"/>
        <!--Day-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,12,2)"/>            <!--Hour-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,15,2)"/>
        <!--Minute-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitStart,18,2)"/>
        <!--Second-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="temp1">
     <xsl:for-each select="relatedTarget/permitExpiry">
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,1,4)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Year-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,6,2)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Month-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,9,2)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Day-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,12,2)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Hour-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,15,2)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Minute-->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(permitExpiry,18,2)" order="descending"/>
        <!--Second-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <target>
     <relatedTarget>
        <permitStart>
           <xsl:value-of select="$temp//permitStart[1]"/>
        </permitStart>
        <permitExpiry>
           <xsl:value-of select="$temp1/permitExpiry[1]"/>
        </permitExpiry>
     </relatedTarget>
  </target>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output :

```
<target>
<relatedTarget>
  <permitStart>2014-07-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
  <permitExpiry>2003-07-12T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
</relatedTarget>
</target>
```

EDIT :

More simplified version :

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="target">
  <xsl:variable name="permitStartVar" select="//permitStart"/>
  <xsl:variable name="permitStopVar" select="//permitExpiry"/>

  <xsl:variable name="temp">
     <xsl:for-each select="relatedTarget/permitStart">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="temp1">
     <xsl:for-each select="relatedTarget/permitExpiry">
        <xsl:sort select="."  order="descending"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <target>
     <relatedTarget>
        <permitStart>
           <xsl:value-of select="$temp//permitStart[1]"/>
        </permitStart>
        <permitExpiry>
           <xsl:value-of select="$temp1/permitExpiry[1]"/>
        </permitExpiry>
     </relatedTarget>
  </target>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In your simplified version you are using XSLT 1.0, to access the temp1 variable in 1.0 as a node set you need to use exsl extension or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Sivaa for the solution works fine for my xslt 1.0 version. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without sorting by using `max()` and `min()` on the `xs:dateTime` values.

Example

**XML Input**

```
<target>
    <relatedTarget>
        <permitExpiry>2005-07-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2015-07-11T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>

    <relatedTarget>
        <permitExpiry>2003-07-12T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2014-07-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>

    <relatedTarget>
        <permitExpiry>2002-07-10T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2016-07-06T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>
</target>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <target>
            <relatedTarget>
                <xsl:copy-of select="(relatedTarget/permitStart[.=min(/*/relatedTarget/xs:dateTime(permitStart))])[1]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="(relatedTarget/permitExpiry[.=max(/*/relatedTarget/xs:dateTime(permitExpiry))])[1]"/>
            </relatedTarget>
        </target>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<target>
   <relatedTarget>
      <permitStart>2014-07-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
      <permitExpiry>2005-07-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
   </relatedTarget>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this solution works only with XSLT version 2.0.

Comment: @SunDante - That is correct and since your question is tagged xslt-2.0, it should work for you. If this question was only for 1.0, please update the tags.