# Sorting in xslt and choosing minimum or maximum value dependent on other child nodes

Tags: sorting, xslt-1.0

```
<target>
    <relatedTarget>
        <status>pass</status>
        <permitExpiry>2005-08-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2015-07-11T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>

    <relatedTarget>
        <status>fail</status>
        <permitExpiry>2003-09-12T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2014-04-01T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>

    <relatedTarget>
        <status>pass</status>
        <permitExpiry>2002-07-10T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
        <permitStart>2016-05-06T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
    </relatedTarget>
</target>
```

I want final output as

```
<target>
        <relatedTarget>
            <status>pass</status>
            <permitExpiry>2005-08-02T08:11:00.000Z</permitExpiry>
            <permitStart>2015-05-11T09:22:00.000Z</permitStart>
        </relatedTarget>
</target>
```

Output should contain the minimum start date (excluding the dates in relatedTarget with status=fail) and maximum end date (excluding the dates in relatedTarget with status=fail) as can be seen from the values above.
Modified version of this question: [Sorting in xslt and choosing minimum or maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681911/3826280)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @michael.hor257k i need one related target block from the multiple blocks in the input. this should contain the maximum and minimum dates. However the dates from the blocks where <status>fail</status> should not be considered

Comment: That's not a question. That's a request. StackOverflow is not a coding service. If you have a specific question or difficulty, you are welcome to ask for help.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i am sorry u missunderstood. I am not using this forum as a coding service. I am new to XSLT henc this question logic i am not getting....